# Apache Reverse Proxy based on subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, subdomain, reverse-proxy

I am currently trying to set up Apache2 as reverse proxy rewriting based on a subdomain's hostname.

Any request sent to `*.accepted-terms.mydomain.tld` should be forwarded to a local port using the `Host` `*.mydomain.tld`. Simply, the `.accepted-terms` in the middle should be cut away.

Eg

- `foo.accepted-terms.mydomain.tld` → `foo.mydomain.tld:6443`
- `bar.accepted-terms.mydomain.tld` → `bar.mydomain.tld:6443`

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        [...] # SSL Certificates

        SSLProxyEngine On
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ServerName accepted-terms.mydomain.tld
        ServerAlias *.accepted-terms.mydomain.tld

        ProxyPass / https://0.0.0.0:6443/
        ProxyPassReverse / https://0.0.0.0:6443/

#-------- Here, the fun starts:

        SetEnvIf Host ^(.*)accepted-terms\.mydomain\.tld$ new_host=$1
        RequestHeader set Host %{new_host}emydomain.tld

#------- Here, the fun should be done.

        RequestHeader set Cookie "disclaimer_accepted=true"
</VirtualHost>
```

Unfortunately, my tries based on `SetEncIf` and the `Host` were unsuccessful. Is there any way to realize this?

Comment: `SetEnvIf` and `RequestHeader` works on my Apache and I am getting `Host` header. Where do you see it missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        # [...] SSL

        SSLProxyEngine On
        SSLProxyCheckPeerName Off
        ServerName accepted-terms.mydomain.tld
        ServerAlias *.accepted-terms.mydomain.tld

        SetEnvIf Host ^(.*).accepted.onionroot.network$ new_host=$1

        RequestHeader set Host %{new_host}e.onionroot.network
        RequestHeader set Cookie "disclaimer_accepted=true"

        ProxyPreserveHost On

        ProxyPass / https://0.0.0.0:6443/ retry=1 acquire=3000 timeout=600 Keepalive=On
        ProxyPassReverse / https://0.0.0.0:6443/

</VirtualHost>
```

It seems like **reordering the configuration** solved the issues.